# Manually loading .deb files during docker container build

Tags: linux, bash, docker

I am trying to write a bash script which checks for a docker image. If it does exist, a container based on the image is created. If it doesnt, first the image is built and then the container is started.

I have a dockerfile to create this image which contains a ROS installation and custom RVIZ plugins. These are available as `.deb` files, but I fail to install them in the image.

Manually, I would first start the container and then add them by running `dpkg -s /my/additional/extensions`. This is possible because I mounted the folder where I have the `/assets` directory into my workspace while running it. However, if I build the container I still do not have the environment variables set. As far as I understand this is where `COPY` is used within the dockerfile, but I fail to understand how it is used.

My bash script preparing the folder structure looks the following:

```
    #first create directories, then copy assets and build image
    printf "build ROS image with extensions from base image with docker file\n"
    [ -d $HOME/docker/ros_kinetic ] && cd $HOME/docker/ros_kinetic || { mkdir $HOME/docker/ros_kinetic ; cd $HOME/docker/ros_kinetic; }
    [ -d $HOME/docker/ros_kinetic/workspace ]  ||  mkdir $HOME/docker/ros_kinetic/workspace
    [ -d $HOME/docker/ros_kinetic/workspace/assets ]  ||  mkdir $HOME/docker/ros_kinetic/workspace/assets  
    
    #copy assets (RVIZ extensions, dockerfile and RVIZ viz)
    cp -r $CWD/assets .
    cp $CWD/some_dockerfile .
    cp $CWD/some_viz.rviz ./workspace
    mv assets/ros-kinetic-* ./workspace/assets
    printf "Copy executed\n"
    
    #build image from docker file
    docker build -t $CONTAINER_NAME -f $CWD/ros_kinetic_dockerfile . && printf " Build completed, starting container\n"
```

in the dockerfile, the COPY command then is the issue - I seem to use a wrong filepath. Once the container runs, the folder would be `/home/$USER/workspace/assets`

```
#copy RVIZ plugin to docker container
COPY $HOME/docker/ros_kinetic/workspace/assets/ros-kinetic-* /root/home/$USER/workspace/assets

#install additional RVIZ plugin packages necessary for radar visualization in RVIZ
# .deb files need to be in subfolder ./assets
RUN cd /root/home/$USER/workspace/assets
RUN dpkg -i ros-kinetic-eot-track-msgs_0.6.0-0.2gt_xenial_amd64.deb
RUN dpkg -i ros-kinetic-rviz-plugin-display-eot-track-array_3.0.0-0.2gt_xenial_amd64.deb
RUN dpkg -i ros-kinetic-rviz-plugin-display-radar-detection-array_1.2.3-0.2gt_xenial_amd64.deb
```

When I execute the script, I always get the following error: `COPY $HOME/docker/ros_kinetic/workspace/assets/ros-kinetic-* /root/home/$USER/workspace/assets COPY failed: no source files were specified`. What am I doing wrong? I've reworked the command several times by now and it always fails in different ways.

Edit:

now I've tried modifying the dockerfile according to this page: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#understand-build-context which basically says that the directory of the dockerfile will be handed over recursively to the docker daemon and then can be accessed. I've removed the `mv` statement in the bash script, meaning that I should be able to install the extensions like this:

```
RUN dpkg -i assets/ros-kinetic-*
```

This still returns the following error:

`dpkg: error processing archive assets/ros-kinetic-* (--install): cannot access archive: No such file or directory Errors were encountered while processing: assets/ros-kinetic-*`

Comment: Please have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy). COPY is relative to the build context and you cannot get out of it.

Comment: Tangentially, `RUN cd` is pointless, the directory will be changed back as soon as the `RUN` statement finishes. You are probably looking for `WORKDIR`.

Comment: The documentation says that all the directory of the build context (meaning the dckerfile? ) will be handed over recursively. My working directory contains the dockerfile, the `/assets/` folder and the bash script. In the assets folder, there are several .deb extensions. If I am not completely wrong, according to https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#understand-build-context, a simple `RUN dpkg -i assets/ros-kinetic-*` should do the trick. However, this returns an error? `cannot access archive: No such file or directory`

Comment: This was my very first try, I've read the documentation but I feel like I am not understanding it 100%. And since I've already spent considerable time on it I`ve asked you guys. I am not seeing the issue here. Sorry if it's a simple thing but I fail to understand it.